# "basic page" content type: how would I restrict access to a page for only 1 role

Tags: redirection, users

If I created content that is of "basic page" content type that is mapped to a URL path settings as an alias how would I restrict access to that page to only 1 role?

If the user is not logged on then how can I redirect the user to a login page and then after that send them back page to the originally requested page?

Note I only want to restrict access for this one page and not all pages that have "basic page" content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hook_node_view()`

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $user = $GLOBALS['user'];
  // Check user->roles
  // If user hasn't access to current node
  drupal_set_message(t('You have to login before continue...'), 'status');
  drupal_goto('user', array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/' . $node->nid)));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be acheived by using a combination of [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and [login toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) modules. You'll be able to restrict pages and prompt user to login to access them.

Answer (score 1):

The [Anonymous Login](http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_login) module will intercept restricted page requests from anonymous users, give them a login form, then take them back to the requested page when they are logged in.

You can certainly restrict access to a single role on a particular page using [Content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access). Just go to the Access Control tab of the content type and check 'Enable per content node access control settings '.

The problem as I see it is that the drupal menu system checks a user's access permissions before displaying a menu item, so your anonymous users and the users without the restricted role will never be able to go to the restricted content through a menu item. The only way to direct them to the content is through a hard coded link in a page or an email.